# Failed Using C# To start TASM

Tags: c#, process, assembly, tasm

Thanks before, i experienced some problem. I'm on project working on my Assembly IDE. I use TASM for the compiler. My C# Code fro compiling is this :

```
void Compile(string file){
    ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("tasm.exe",file);
    Process.Start(pInfo);
}
```

But i dont know why, when i open TASM with this code. TASM only show a blank black screen. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void Compile(string file){
    Process.Start("tasm.exe",file);
}
```

That seems more inline with the examples given here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx

I'm assuming 'file' is the full path to the assembly source file you want to assembly.

Comment: Yeah, its the full path to the assembly source file. But, sorry.. TASM still show blank screen and nothing happens.

Comment: The above is the same as the OP's code snippet.  Just using the `Start()` overload.

Comment: @linuxuser27 thanks for the clarification. My guess is there's a specific setting you need in order for it to work with console applications.